# Enable global method security leads to 404

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-security

When I enable Global Method Security, I get `404/NotFound` when I call my endpoint that belongs to a class annotated with `@Preauthorized`

This is my configuration:

```
@Configuration @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true, jsr250Enabled = true)
class MethodSecurityConfig : GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration()
```

And this is the controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(Endpoints.BABBLE.ROOT)
@PreAuthorize("@authenticator.checkIfThunderkickAdmin()")
class BabbleRequestController() {

    @PostMapping(Endpoints.BABBLE.APPEND)
    public fun balances(@RequestBody requestData: AppendRequestData, @RequestHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION)  authHeader : String): ResponseEntity<String> {
    ...
```

Comment: Did you try to set `proxyTargetClass = true` for `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you got `404` because you have `@PreAuthorize` and missing `proxyTargetClass = true` for `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity` annotation.  Spring loses your controller because it's a JDK proxy instead of CGLIB and doesn't have `@RestController` anymore.

Try to replace it with:

```java
@Configuration @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true, jsr250Enabled = true, proxyTargetClass = true)
class MethodSecurityConfig : GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration()
```